# Rounding a number up to the nearest ten

Tags: python, rounding

I need a piece of code in my program which will get a number, "dSum" in my code, and round it **up** to the nearest ten. For example, if dSum is 33, I need dSumRounded to be 40. The line of code I already have is wrong, it seems to be rounding **down** to the nearest ten. I found that piece of code from another stackoverflow question, but it just isn't working in this situation.

```
import math #Imports the math library

def findCheckDigit():
    code = input("Please enter your 7 digit code: ")  #Makes a function and sets the code to a variable

    d1 = int(code[0]) * 3
    d2 = int(code[1]) * 1
    d3 = int(code[2]) * 3
    d4 = int(code[3]) * 1    #Seperates each digit and assigns it to a variable, multiplying it by 3 or 1 
    d5 = int(code[4]) * 3
    d6 = int(code[5]) * 1
    d7 = int(code[6]) * 3

    dSum = d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5 + d6 + d7      #Adds each digit together
    dSumRounded = int(math.ceil(dSum / 10.0)) * 10   #Gets the rounded up version of the sum of the digits
    checkDigit = dSumRounded - dSum   #Makes the check digit equal to the sum of digits taken away from the rounded up sum of digits

    print(dSumRounded)
    print("Your check digit is: " + str(checkDigit))   #Prints the check digit
```

Comment: I tried and it works (33 is rounded to 40)

Comment: do all numbers round up, does 31 also go to 40?

Comment: Okay, I've noticed the problem. I've tried other 7 digit codes, but it's 2222222 what is returning 0 for some reason. There seems to be a problem somewhere, but I'm stumped.

Comment: I set `dsum=2222222` and saw that `int(math.ceil(dsum/10.0))*10` yields      `2222230`, as one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer staying in integerland.

```
>>> for i in range(20, 40):
        print(i, '->', (i + 9) // 10 * 10)

20 -> 20
21 -> 30
22 -> 30
23 -> 30
24 -> 30
25 -> 30
26 -> 30
27 -> 30
28 -> 30
29 -> 30
30 -> 30
31 -> 40
32 -> 40
33 -> 40
34 -> 40
35 -> 40
36 -> 40
37 -> 40
38 -> 40
39 -> 40
```

That said, your own expression `int(math.ceil(dSum / 10.0)) * 10` works, too.

Comment: This will work with integral types but you will hit snags with floating point types.

Comment: Right. Their numbers are integers, though.

Comment: Just sayin' ;-) An early Java implementation used to use a constant for rounding, with disastrous consequences.